# Dataset row position changed by GroupBy in 11.0.1

Tags: bugs, dataset, sorting, gathering

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

In 10.4.1 and previous versions then using `GroupBy` in a `Dataset` `Query` the order that the rows appeared in the ungrouped dataset matched those in the grouped dataset.  However, in 11.0.1 the order changes in an unintuitive manner. This is terrible for me as I produce structured reports from `Dataset`s (using nested `KeyValueMap`s and the like) where the order the records important. Now all of these reports have jumbled grids and tables as a result.

```
Dataset[AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, #] & /@
   {
    {"cat", "dog", 1, 2, 3},
    {"cat", "dog", 4, 5, 6},
    {"cat", "mouse", 1, 2, 3},
    {"cat", "mouse", 4, 5, 6},
    {"bird", "rat", 1, 2, 3},
    {"bird", "rat", 4, 5, 6},
    {"bird", "worm", 1, 2, 3},
    {"bird", "worm", 4, 5, 6},
    {"horse", "goat", 1, 2, 3},
    {"horse", "goat", 4, 5, 6},
    {"horse", "pig", 1, 2, 3},
    {"horse", "pig", 4, 5, 6}
    }][GroupBy[{#"A" &, #"B" &}]]
```

## In 10.4.1 and previous versions

Order is preserved; cat, bird, horse.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## In 11.0.1

Order is changed to horse, cat, bird. The changing order has no immediate structure to it in the real data although here it may look as if it is reverse alphabetical.  The real data has longer strings for groups and subgroups with many more groups and subgroups.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is not related to the new formatting of `Dataset`s in 11.0.1 because if I set `` Dataset`$UseNewDatasetFormatting = False `` I get the pre-11 formatting but the order is still broken.

I feel this is a bug. Thoughts?  Version 11.0.1 on Win 7 Ent SP1

**Update**
 Confirmed bug CASE:3736993

Comment: Is Dataset explicitly ordered? I believe in other languages similar structures typically are not.

Comment: @user6014 In *Mathematica* things tend to stay as entered.  Well, that has been my experience in the parts of it that I use.

Comment: I agree, but if something isn't explicitly "ordered" than it isn't unreasonable or incorrect for it to rearrange itself. It's not ideal that it may rearrange itself inconsistently between versions... but it's technically not incorrect I think. Just some thoughts, other people may be able to speak with more authority on the paradigm.

Comment: @user6014 Yes, all *data structures* in Mathematica are ordered, including associations.  What *functions* operating on them do is a separate issue.  The documentation of `GroupBy` doesn't say anything about ordering.  This contrasts with `GatherBy`, which keeps the ordering intact according to its docs.  BTW there's no need for `Dataset` to reproduce this, just a `GroupBy` on the underlying list of associations will do.

Comment: @user6014 I think I disagree with you a little bit.  Unless explicitly mentioned in the documentation for that function, I *expect* every operation applied to my dataset to maintain the original structure.

Comment: I understand why you were surprised by this, but I also wouldn't call this a bug.  Ultimately the question is: what was the intention of the people who implemented it?  The documentation isn't always accurate so just because the order is not documented doesn't mean that they didn't mean to preserve it ... So it may be worth reporting to support.  But I suspect that the support person will just tell you that GroupBy gives no guarantees about ordering, possibly even without passing the message to developers.

Comment: Fair enough and I agree with your points. I was ignorant with my assumptions. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Given the high similarity to `GatherBy` they should at least mention that there are no guarantees about ordering.  Maybe under a Possible Issues heading.  Up til now I assumed that GroupBy and GatherBy work the same way.

Comment: I would still contact support and tell them you found the docs unclear.  These are perfectly reasonable suggestions.

Comment: Contacted WRI to see what they have to say about it.  I think it is a bug since it was *working* before and version 11.0.0/1 have a few meaty bugs as it concerns `Datasets`.